# Getting the lowest price in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, min, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have 2 sheets that are set up like this:

- Sheet A is a log with 2 columns, (Item Code, Price). Item codes are
  not unique and there may be multiple rows with similar item codes
  (i.e., Item 1 was sold at $1 today and it was sold at $0.5 last week)
- Sheet B is sort of a lookup sheet (with similar columns to Sheet A) whereupon filling the item code, the price column will
  automatically be filled with the lowest price of that item code from
  Sheet A

I've done some searching and figured that to get the values to be filled in automatically in Sheet B, a `vlookup` would be sufficient. However, `vlookup` only returns the value of the first instance of the index.

Is anyone able to guide me on how I might be able to get the lowest price from Sheet A to show on Sheet B?

Comment: `MINIFS` [doc ref](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014063?hl=en)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use your `VLOOKUP` fx with sorted 2nd parameter:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1:A, SORT('Sheet A'!A:B, 2, 1), 2, 0)))
```

Comment: Great that helped a lot! ArrayFormula() was especially helpful too. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use MINIFS to find minimum value for a given Item code. MINIFS, MAXIFS and SUMIFS are used to find single value from a list of values under some specific conditions.
Formula would be similar to this:

```
= MINIFS(Sheet$1A2:Sheet$1A5, Sheet$1B2:Sheet$1B5, "=ItemCode")
```

Find more on this here, [link](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014063?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Use Query like this:

```
=query(filter(SheetA!A2:B,A2:A<>""),"Select Col1, Min(Col2) Group By Col1 Label Min(Col2) ''")
```

or

```
=ifna({UNIQUE( SheetA!A2:A ), ARRAYFORMULA( vlookup( UNIQUE( SheetA!A2:A ), sort( SheetA!A2:B, 1, true, 2, true ), 2, 0 ))})
```